# Leer un archivo por consola con java

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo el siguiente codigo que me permite leer el contenido de un archivo (en este caso txt) por consola en Java. No entiendo muy bien cual es la función de FileInputStream, InputStreamReader y BufferedReader. ¿Qué es lo que hacen exactamente?. Gracias!

```
public class LeerFichero {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numero = 0;
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del fichero: ");
        String nombreFichero = sc.nextLine();
        String salida = "C:\\Users\\SAG\\Desktop\\Repaso\\src\\leerarchivo\\";
        FileInputStream fichero = new FileInputStream(salida + nombreFichero + ".txt");
        InputStreamReader osw = new InputStreamReader(fichero);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(osw);
        while(br.ready()) {
            String linea = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(linea);
        }

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Flujo de entrada y salida de datos en el sistema de ficheros

**.I/O Streams**

Para cualquier flujo de datos de entrada o salida se usan objetos denominados streams, que transportan los datos entre el programa y cualquier otro agente externo, por ejemplo un dispositivo de hardware, la entrada de comandos desde la consola, la comunicación con otros programas o la lectura y escritura de ficheros.

---

**Java divide la arquitectura de streams en dos grandes grupos:**

1. Los que trabajan con bytes
2. Y los que lo hacen con caracteres.

*Dentro de estos dos grupos existe una estructura de clases capaz de dar formato a los datos,* por ejemplo para leer un byte, un carácter, tipos primitivos o incluso un objeto. También se dispone de búferes para optimizar el rendimiento en la lectura/escritura de datos.

**. Distinguimos los siguientes tipos de streams:**

> **1.** Byte Streams: Leen o escriben datos en bytes.

Son implementaciones de las clases `java.io.InputStream` y `java.io.OutputStream`.

Entre estas podemos encontrar clases como..

- . FileInputStream
- . FileOutputStream

  -. Estas clases pueden ser instanciadas pasando la ruta a un fichero en el constructor de la clase. *A tener en cuenta capturar las posibles excepciones.* Normalmente serán derivadas de `java.io.IOException`.

**. Una vez abierto el stream, se procederá a leer o escribir de forma secuencial hasta el final del fichero.**

**Entrada y salida de datos binarios:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

> **2**. Character Streams: El uso es similar a los byte stream, pero en este caso leeremos ficheros de texto carácter a carácter.

Las implementaciones más usadas de este tipo de *streams* son **`FileReader`** y **`FileWriter`**:

-. **`Un InputStreamReader`** es un puente entre las secuencias de bytes y las secuencias de caracteres: lee los bytes y los decodifica en caracteres utilizando un juego de caracteres específico.

-. Para una mayor eficiencia, hay que considerar envolver un `InputStreamReader` dentro de un `BufferedReader`.

Por ejemplo: `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`

**Entrada y Salida de datos Alfanuméricos:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

> **3**. Buffered Streams: Este tipo de streams los utilizaremos acompañados de otros streams, creando búferes para optimizar el rendimiento del programa.

**`BufferedReader:`** Lee texto de una secuencia de entrada de caracteres, almacenando en el búfer los caracteres para proporcionar la lectura eficiente de esos caracteres, arrays y líneas. De una forma más clara nos permite leer texto de un InputStream de una forma sencilla.

Answer (score 0):

**FileInputStream** sirve para leer, es prácticamente igual que con **FileReader**, usando el método **read()**, cuando llega al final del fichero devuelve -1. Su diferencia básica es que con **FileReader** leemos caracteres y **FileInputStream** lee **bytes**. Por ejemplo:

```
import java.io.*;
public class FicherosBinariosApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try(FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("D:\\fichero_bin.ddr")){

            int valor=fis.read();
            while(valor!=-1){
                System.out.print((char)valor);
                valor=fis.read();
            }

        }catch(IOException e){

        }

    }

}
```

Para java, una clase **Reader** es una clase que lee caracteres. Esto se parece más a lo que queremos. Un **Reader** tiene métodos para leer caracteres. Con esta clase ya podriamos trabajar. La pena es que seguimos teniendo **System.in**, que es un **InputStream** y no un **Reader**.

¿Cómo convertimos el **System.in** en **Reader**?. Hay una clase en java, la **InputStreamReader**, que nos hace esta conversión. Para obtener un **Reader**, únicamente tenemos que instanciar un **InputStreamReader** pasándole en el constructor un **InputStream**. El código es el siguiente

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
```

Estamos declarando una variable *"isr"* de tipo **InputStreamReader**. Creamos un objeto de esta clase haciendo **new InputStreamReader(...)**. Entre paréntesis le pasamos el **InputStream** que queremos convertir a **Reader**, en este caso, el **System.in**

Ya tenemos el **Reader**. ¿Cómo funciona exactamente?

**InputStreamReader** es un **Reader**. Se comporta igual que in **Reader** y se puede poner en cualquier sitio que admita un **Reader**. Es decir, podemos leer de él caracteres.
Al constuirlo le hemos pasado un **InputStream**, en concreto, **System.in.** **InputStreamReader** de alguna forma se lo guarda dentro.
Cuando a **InputStreamReader** le pedimos caracteres, él le pide al **InputStream** que tiene guardado dentro los bytes, los convierte a caracteres y nos los devuelve.

El mecanismo para obtener un **BufferedReader** a partir de otro **Reader** cualquiera (por ejemplo el **InputStreamReader**), es similar al que usamos antes. Lo instanciamos pasándole en el construtor el **Reader**. El código es:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (isr);
```

El funcionamiento de esta clase es igual que el **InputStreamReader**. Cuando le pedimos una línea completa de caracteres (un **String**), ella se lo pide al Reader que tenga dentro, los convierte en **String** y nos lo devuelve.

Para pedirle un **String**, se usa el método **readLine()**. Este método lee todos los caracteres tecleados (recibidos si fuera otro dispositivo de entrada) hasta que encuentra la pulsación de la tecla ,  o como quieras llamarla.

```
String texto = br.readLine();
```

Esto lee del teclado un **String** completo y lo guarda en una variable "texto".

Answer (score -1):

espero que esto te sirva:
https://www.discoduroderoer.es/clases-fileinputstream-y-fileoutputstream-para-ficheros-binarios-en-java/

http://www.javamexico.org/foros/comunidad/outputstream_y_inputstream_que_significa_y_como_trabaja
con esto espero que te quede claro

principalmente sirven para manipulacion de archivos

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, pero sigo sin entenderlo :S

Comment: Links a otros sitios pueden romperse. Es buena practica copiar el contenido relevante dentro de la respuesta para que tenga sentido en un futuro =)